# Identify type of devices in an IT Environment using C# (i.e. Windows, Linux, Network etc)

Tags: visual-studio, c#-4.0, ssh, wmi, autodiscovery

I have to scan my Infrastructure and find it out the way I should use (WMI, SSH, SNMP, etc.) to discover the device details.

The approach I am following as of now is

1. Get the availability of device.
2. 1. Query using WMI (If responding? use this protocol to discover this device)
   2. If the above device does not respond to WMI use another protocol like SSH or SNMP (it's configurable) etc.

Is there any other way of discovery for a mixed environment? Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

The approach you are taking seems reasonable. Alternatively, you could have some existing software do this for you.